# Explanation of PHP array foreach scope within function

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code:

```
$car1 = new Car('Ford','Fusion');
$car2 = new Car('Chevy', 'Avalanche');
$car3 = new Car('Ford', 'F150');

$cars = array($car1, $car2, $car3);

function getCarsByMake($carMake){
    foreach($cars as $car){
        if($car->make == $carMake){
            echo 'Car: ' . $car->make . ' ' . $car->model . "<br>";
        }
    }
}

getCarsByMake('Ford');
```

I get the error that `$cars` in the `foreach` statement is undefined. However, as I understand it, the `$cars` array should be global in scope? If I pass the array into the function through the constructor it works fine. But I'm wondering why I can't access the array in this way.

Comment: use `global $cars;` inside the function. Just above foreach loop

Comment: function is just like a room, and the cars is outside the room, so you need to drag the car to the room so you can modify it inside the room

Comment: Passing the $cars into the function makes it a lot easier to test, you can pass in various versions to check the function reacts as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Add the `global` keyword

   ```
   function getCarsByMake($carMake){
      global $cars;
      foreach($cars as $car){
          if($car->make == $carMake){
              echo 'Car: ' . $car->make . ' ' . $car->model . "<br>";
          }
      }
   }
   ```
2. Use the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array:

   ```
   function getCarsByMake($carMake){
       foreach($GLOBALS["cars"] as $car){
           if($car->make == $carMake){
               echo 'Car: ' . $car->make . ' ' . $car->model . "<br>";
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Although I'd still recommend passing it as an explicit parameter as that makes the code more readable and maintainable, IMHO.

Comment: Any reason why you'd suggest using it as a parameter? Another user advised another method over it.

Comment: Because IMHO it makes the code less readable and less maintainable. Within your function you can never be sure where the global variable comes from and where (or if) it is initialized. And from outside it is not obvious to a caller that the function needs and works on the global variable `cars`.

Answer (score 6):

Along with Exprator's solution, you could also pass the `$cars` array to the function like this.

```
function getCarsByMake($carMake, $cars){
    foreach($cars as $car){
        if($car->make == $carMake){
            echo 'Car: ' . $car->make . ' ' . $car->model . "<br>";
        }
    }
}

getCarsByMake('Ford', $cars);
```

Comment: Yep, I made a note in my original post that this method did work for me, I was just wondering about the scope of the variable itself. Thanks!

Comment: @Reed You should accept an answer, whichever one works the best in your case.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getCarsByMake($carMake){
    global $cars;
    foreach($cars as $car){
        if($car->make == $carMake){
            echo 'Car: ' . $car->make . ' ' . $car->model . "<br>";
        }
    }
}

getCarsByMake('Ford');
```

its because the function is not getting the `$cars` , you need to globally access it inside the function

Comment: Is there any explanation to this besides just being a nature of the language?

Comment: @Reed Your variable is not in the global scope unless declared global.

Comment: the reason is OOPs @Reed

Answer (score 0):

You can call $cars globally but you can also try by another way according to your code.Ex:

```
$car1 = new Car('Ford','Fusion');
$car2 = new Car('Chevy', 'Avalanche');
$car3 = new Car('Ford', 'F150');

$cars = array($car1, $car2, $car3);

function getCarsByMake($carMake,$cars){
    foreach($cars as $car){
        if($car->make == $carMake){
            echo 'Car: ' . $car->make . ' ' . $car->model . "<br>";
        }
    }
}

getCarsByMake('Ford',$cars);
```